# What's the difference between these constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, difference

I'd like to know what is the difference between these two constructors:

```
List<type*> list = List<type*>();
```

and

```
List<type*> list;
```

The container *List* was written by me and has a user-defined constructor which takes no parameters.

In my opinion the first line is correct and the second one looks like Java. However, both compile. So, what is the difference between these two statements?

Comment: There's no such thing as "a (non-default) constructor which takes no parameters".

Comment: Then how will you call a constructor which I wrote which doesn't take any parameters? It isn't default, is it?

Comment: @user2738748 It's user-defined default constructor.

Comment: A *default* construtor is a construtor which is called when the user didn't define any other construtors, isn't it?

Comment: @user2738748, a default constructor is a constructor which doesn't take any parameters. It can be either compiler generated or user defined. It's still called a default constructor.

Comment: If you don't believe us, why don't you look it up?

Comment: Because I didn't believe you. Ok, I looked it up, I see - my mistake.

Comment: "Because"? You know that doesn't make sense, don't you?

Comment: What doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 4):

The first one requires an accessible copy or move constructor while the second one does not.

Consider for example this demontsrative program. If you will not use MS VC++ then the program shall not  compile.:)

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:    
    A() {}
private:    
    A( const A& ) { std::cout << "A( const A & )" << std::endl; }
};              

int main()
{
    A a = A();
}
```

because the copy constructor is inaccessible even if otherwise the copy operation could be elided.

Also using the first one provides that the corresponding object will be value-initialized while using the second one provides that the corresponding object will be default initialized.

Comment: Why does the first line require a copy constructor? There is nothing to copy.  Also, when there is no accessible copy constructor if there is always a default copy constructor or a copy constructor written by the user? Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @user2738748 In fact a temporary object created in the right side is copied/moved to the object declared in the left side. If for example you will declare the copy constructor as private then the code should not compile.

Comment: What do you mean there's nothing to copy? There's a freshly created List object on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example:) But why will the code compile if I use MS VC++? The idea of a method being public or private shouldn't depend on the compiler.

Comment: @user2738748 The MS VC++ has its own language extentions or peculirities that do not satisfy the C++ Standard.:)

Comment: Thank you for all your explanations:)